# Chunk array by three in PHP (in JS it works out)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, cut

as title says I wanna chunk an array by three and display results each in a single row.

In JS no problems:

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let i, arr, j;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3) {

 arr = array.slice(i, i + 3);
 let div = document.createElement("div");
 div.classList.add('row');

 for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
  let par = document.createElement("p");
  let res = document.createTextNode(arr[j]);
  par.appendChild(res);
  div.appendChild(par);
 }

document.body.appendChild(div);

}
```

Getting correctly:

```
<div class="row">
 <p>1</p>
 <p>2</p>
 <p>3</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <p>4</p>
 <p>5</p>
 <p>6</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <p>7</p>
</div>
```

In PHP, with this:

```
<?php
  $array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i += 3) :
    $arr = array_slice($array, $i, $i + 3);
?>

  <div class="row">
    <?= implode(" ", $arr); ?>
  </div>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

I get:

```
<div class="row">
 <p>1</p>
 <p>2</p>
 <p>3</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <p>4</p>
 <p>5</p>
 <p>6</p>
 <p>7</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <p>7</p>
</div>
```

I always get the middle row wrong (even if you increase $array), what am I missing? :/

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter of [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is the length and not the end point, so change it to...

```
$arr = array_slice($array, $i, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `array_slice` in PHP and `slice` in JS aren't quite the same. PHP takes a start and a length, whereas JS takes a start and an end.

PHP:

```
array_slice(array $array, int $offset, int $length = NULL);
```

JS:

```
arr.slice(begin, end)
```

So you can't quite just copy the implementation over from one to the other. If you change your PHP line to:

```
$arr = array_slice($array, $i, 3);
```

(just specifying the length **3** instead of **$i + 3**), then it should work correctly.

Alternatively in PHP, you could just use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.array-chunk.php), and loop over the resulting chunks.

Answer (score 1):

**You may use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) in php**

```
<?php
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_chunk($array, 3));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's already `array_chunk` function:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 3);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {?>
    <div class="row">
        <?= implode(" ", $chunk); ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 3);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
  // Do whatever you want with chunks: e.g.:
  implode(" ", $chunk);
}
```